# How to combine SELECT DISTINCT and ROWNUM in Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine the two MySQL statements below into a single ORACLE query if possible.

The initial query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME FROM PEOPLE WHERE LAST_NAME IN ("Smith","Jones","Gupta")
```

then based on each FIRST_NAME returned I query

```
SELECT * 
FROM PEOPLE 
WHERE FIRST_NAME = {FIRST_NAME} 
  AND LAST_NAME IN ("Smith","Jones","Gupta") 
ORDER BY FIELD(LAST_NAME, "Smith","Jones","Gupta") DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

The "List of last names" serves as a "default / override" indicator, so I only have one person for each first name, and where multiple rows for the same first name exist, only the Last match from the list of "Last Names" is used.

I need a SQL query that returns the last row from the "in" clause based on the order of the values in the IN(a,b,c). Here is a sample table, and the results I need from the query.

For the Table PEOPLE, with values

```
LAST_NAME    FIRST_NAME
.....
Smith        Mike    
Smith        Betty
Smith        Jane
Jones        Mike
Jones        Sally
....
```

I need a query based on DISTINCT FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME IN ('Smith','Jones') that returns

```
Betty Smith
Jane Smith
Mike Jones
Sally Jones
```

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  I recognize `field()` as a MySQL function not an Oracle function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select first_name, last_name
from (
  select p.first_name,
         p.last_name,
         row_number() over (partition by p.first_name
                            order by case p.last_name
                                     when 'Smith' then 1
                                     when 'Jones' then 2
                                     when 'Gupta' then 3
                                     end desc) as rn
  from people p
  where p.last_name in ('Smith','Jones','Gupta')
)
where rn = 1;
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2088e/4)

**EDIT**

It's not hard to get more columns. I'm sure you could have figured it out with a bit more effort:

```
select *
from (
  select p.*,
         row_number() over (partition by p.first_name
                            order by case p.last_name
                                     when 'Smith' then 1
                                     when 'Jones' then 2
                                     when 'Gupta' then 3
                                     end desc) as rn
  from people p
  where p.last_name in ('Smith','Jones','Gupta')
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! Unfortunately I did not state the problem clearly enough, in that there are columns other than first and last name that I need, and adding a * to the columns selected is returning the "FROM keyword not found where expected" error. Can you update your answer to support * in the columns?

Comment: Well, I edited my answer.  But I think you could have figured out the extra requirement on your own with a little effort.

Answer (score 3):

Or like this:

```
select first_name, 
       max(last_name) 
           keep (dense_rank first order by decode(last_name,
                                                  'Smith', 1,
                                                  'Jones', 2,
                                                  'Gupta', 3) desc)
 group by first_name
```

Oracle "FIRST"/"LAST" functions allow to get values from other columns of row with maximum/minimum value (for example get last_name of employee with maximum salary, or like in this case - get last_name from row with maximum rank)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: Thank you for answering the question! Unfortunately I did not state the problem clearly enough, in that there are columns other than first and last name that I need, and adding a * to the columns selected is returning the "FROM keyword not found where expected" error. Can you update your answer to support * in the columns?

Comment: * will not work here, because you need to group by some columns and select max() keep other columns.
Those columns, you need to be with first_name, add to select list and to group by clause.
Those columns, you need to get first/last from the group, just copypaste 
max()keep block, and mention another column in max(...) instead of last_name.

Or, to avoid max()keep duplication, use Sstan's solution
you may specify p.* there